# What this command "Stsadm" does?

Tags: stsadm

Hello Friends I want to know about this command "Stsadm". Exactly what is this command works? How can we use this command.

Answer (score 3):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=stsadm

Comment: Please refrain from using lmgtfy links in your answers. One of the reasons that people ask questions here is to get the answers from us the community, people that know the product well. Online doco isn't always helpful to someone getting started. Plus our FAQ states that `No question is too trivial or too "newbie"`. Please remember this! Also read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a command line tool for administrative task related to SharePoint. But as James already mentioned, if you search for it on the Internet you'll find plenty of information about it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I want to know one thing also. Is this command can also take backup of MDF File.

Comment: Yep, you use it to back up specific sites (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441(office.12).aspx) If you're wanting to maintain backups for your entire content database, use standard SQL Server backup mechanisms.

Comment: @prettsons: Please ask new questions in a new question. You'll get more attention to your post and it means the upvote/downvote system will work properly. Thanks and welcome to SharePoint Overflow!